# Operator Sum: Selfadjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a closed operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}A\to\mathcal{H}:\quad A=A^{**}$$

Does it follow that:
$$S:=\overline{A+A^*}:\quad S=S^*$$
*(Rigorous proof?)*

Densely defined?
$$S_0:=A+A^*:\quad\overline{\mathcal{D}S_0}=\mathcal{H}\quad\big(\implies\overline{\mathcal{D}S_0^*}=\mathcal{H}\big)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example,
$$
            A = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}
$$
on the domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ of absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^2[0,1]$ for which $f' \in L^2[0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $A^*$ is the same as $A$ except that the condition $f(0)=0$ is replaced by $f(1)=0$. Then $A^{\star\star}=A$ because $A$ is closed and densely-defined. However, $S=A+A^{\star}$ has a domain consisting of absolutely continuous $f\in L^2$ with $f'\in L^2$ and $f(0)=0=f(1)$; and this restriction is a closed operator:
$$
           \overline{A+A^{\star}}=A+A^{\star}.
$$
However, $S \ne S^*$ because $\mathcal{S^*}$ is the restriction of $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ to all absolutely continuous $f \in L^2$ for which $f'\in L^2$, with no endpoint restrictions at all. What you have are strict graph inclusions
$$
              S  \prec A \prec S^* ,\;\;\; S \prec A^* \prec S^*,\\
                     \dim\mathcal{G}(S^*)/\mathcal{G}(S) = 2.
$$

Comment: @Freeze_S : You're welcome. Differentiation is a strange example. On $[0,1]$ there are these issues. On $\mathbb{R}$ it is selfadjoint. On $[0,\infty)$ it is symmetric with no selfadjoint extensions (f(0)=0) and you end up with a half-plane for the spectrum, which is why you get the Laplace transform.

Comment: Yes, differentiation is also a beautiful example. I think the algebraic structure of the domain plays a crucial role here: Magma, Semigroup, Group? Also the measure structure of the domain plays some role: Finite, Infinite? As another example one obtains for polynomials by Gram-Schmidt: Legende, Laguerre, Hermite *(Kreyszig, Section 3.7, Pages 175-185)*